# Making a coffee shop UI

Tags: python, e-commerce

I'm making a user interface for an online coffee shop. I need to call methods that have already been created. The user is also able to make customisations to their drink order such as a different choice of milk, brown or white sugar etc. Once the user choice has been made it will add the drink to their basket. The user also has the option of editing their drinks basket and removing a drink if they so wish.

It will receive information from a file. This code works but is very messy. Are there ways to clean it up and make it neater/less repetitive?

```
from display.output import ConsoleOutput
from user import User
from user.drinks import Drink
from user.drinks.customisations import CustomisationManager, Customisation
from user.drinks.drinks_manager import DrinksManager
from user.drinks.types import SoftDrink, Coffee


class Strings:
    add_customisation_to_drink_yn = "Would you like to add a customisation to your drink? y/n"
    remove_customisation_from_drink = "Would you like to remove a customisation from your drink? y/n"
    change_customisation = "Would you like to change the customisations of your drink? y/n"
    change_size = "Would you like to change the size of your drink? y/n"
    current_drinks = "We currently have these drinks available:"
    add_customisations = "Would you like to add any customisations? y/n"
    current_customisations = "\nWe currently have these customisations available:"
    commands = "\na: add new drink, u: update drink, b: show basket, q: quit, r: remove drink from basket"

    @staticmethod
    def items_in_basket_cost(basket):
        return f"You currently have these items in your basket costing {basket.calculate_cost()}"

    @staticmethod
    def add_drink_to_basket(drinks_manager):
        return f"Which drink would you like to add to your basket? 0-{len(drinks_manager.all_drinks()) - 1}"

    @staticmethod
    def add_size_to_drink(drink, sizes):
        return f"Which size of {drink.name} would you like to add to your drink? 0-{len(sizes) - 1}"

    @staticmethod
    def add_customisation_to_drink(customisations_manager, drink):
        return f"Which customisation would you like to add to your {drink.name}?" \
               + f"0-{len(customisations_manager.all_customisations()) - 1}"

    @staticmethod
    def remove_drink_from_basket(user):
        return f"Which drink would you like to remove from your basket? 0-{len(user.basket.items) - 1}"

    @staticmethod
    def update_drink_in_basket(user):
        return f"Which drink would you like to update in your basket? 0-{len(user.basket.items) - 1}"

    @staticmethod
    def customisation_to_remove(drink):
        return f"Which customisation would you like to remove from your drink? 0-{len(drink.customisations) - 1}"


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.display = Display(input_handler=ConsoleInput(), output_handler=ConsoleOutput())
        self.drink_manager = DrinksManager()
        self.customisation_manager = CustomisationManager()

        self.drink_manager.register_drink(Coffee(1.0, 1, 'Coffee'))
        self.drink_manager.register_drink(SoftDrink(1.0, 2, 'Juice'))
        self.drink_manager.register_drink(Coffee(1.0, 3, 'Milk'))
        self.drink_manager.register_drink(Coffee(1.0, 4, 'Mocha'))
        self.drink_manager.register_drink(Coffee(1.0, 5, 'Cappuccino'))
        self.drink_manager.register_drink(Coffee(1.0, 6, 'Water'))

        self.customisation_manager.register_customisation(Customisation(1, 'White Sugar', 0.3))
        self.customisation_manager.register_customisation(Customisation(2, 'Brown Sugar', 0.6))
        self.customisation_manager.register_customisation(Customisation(3, 'Milk', 0.3))
        self.customisation_manager.register_customisation(Customisation(4, 'Almond Milk', 0.2))
        self.customisation_manager.register_customisation(Customisation(5, 'Cream', 0.8))

        self.user = User()

        self.main_menu()

    def main_menu(self):
        while True:
            print(Strings.commands)
            command = self.display.input.get('Enter a command:')
            print('\n')

            if command == 'a':
                self.list_drinks()
                self.add_drink_to_basket()

            elif command == 'u':
                self.display_basket()
                self.update_drink_in_basket()

            elif command == 'q':
                break

            elif command == 'b':
                self.display_basket()

            elif command == 'r':
                self.remove_drink_from_basket()

    def list_drinks(self):
        self.display.output.print(Strings.current_drinks)
        all_drinks = self.drink_manager.all_drinks()
        for index, drink in enumerate(all_drinks):
            self.display.output.print(f"{index}. {drink.name} -- £{drink.cost}")

    def add_drink_to_basket(self):
        drink_index = int(self.display.input.get(Strings.add_drink_to_basket(self.drink_manager)))
        drink = self.add_customisation_to_drink(self.drink_manager.all_drinks()[drink_index])
        drink = self.add_size_to_drink(drink)
        self.user.basket.add_drink(drink)

    def add_size_to_drink(self, drink: Drink) -> Drink:
        self.list_sizes(drink)
        sizes = drink.available_sizes
        size_index = int(self.display.input.get(Strings.add_size_to_drink(drink, sizes)))

        drink.size = sizes[size_index]

        return drink

    def list_sizes(self, drink: Drink):
        for index, size in enumerate(drink.available_sizes):
            print(f"{index}. {size.value.name} -- {size.value.volume}L, £{size.value.cost_multiplier * drink.cost}")

    def list_customisations(self):
        self.display.output.print(Strings.current_customisations)
        all_customisations = self.customisation_manager.all_customisations()
        for index, customisation in enumerate(all_customisations):
            self.display.output.print(f"{index}. {customisation.name} -- £{customisation.cost}")

    def add_customisation_to_drink(self, drink: Drink) -> Drink:
        while True:
            add_customisation = self.display.input.get(Strings.add_customisations)

            if add_customisation == 'n':
                return drink

            self.list_customisations()
            customisation_index = int(self.display.input.get(
                Strings.add_customisation_to_drink(self.customisation_manager, drink)
            ))
            drink.add_customisation(self.customisation_manager.all_customisations()[customisation_index])

    def display_basket(self):
        basket = self.user.basket
        self.display.output.print(Strings.items_in_basket_cost(basket))
        for drink_index, item in enumerate(basket.items):
            self.display.output.print(f"{drink_index}. {item.name} ({item.size.value.name}): £{item.calculate_cost()}")
            for customisation_index, customisation in enumerate(item.customisations):
                self.display.output.print(f"{' ' * 4} {customisation.name}: {customisation.cost}")

    def remove_drink_from_basket(self):
        self.display_basket()
        drink_index = int(self.display.input.get(
            Strings.remove_drink_from_basket(self.user)
        ))

        self.user.basket.remove_drink(self.user.basket.items[drink_index].id)

    def update_drink_in_basket(self):
        drink_index = int(self.display.input.get(
            Strings.update_drink_in_basket(self.user)
        ))
        drink = self.user.basket.items[drink_index]

        change_size = self.display.input.get(Strings.change_size)
        if change_size == 'y':
            drink = self.add_size_to_drink(drink)

        change_customisation = self.display.input.get(Strings.change_customisation)
        if change_customisation == 'y':
            remove_customisation = self.display.input.get(Strings.remove_customisation_from_drink)
            if remove_customisation == 'y':
                for index, customisation in enumerate(drink.customisations):
                    self.display.output.print(f"{index}. {customisation.name}: {customisation.cost}")
                customisation_index = int(self.display.input.get(
                    Strings.customisation_to_remove(drink)
                ))
                drink.remove_customisation(drink.customisations[customisation_index])
            add_customisation = self.display.input.get(Strings.add_customisation_to_drink_yn)
            if add_customisation == 'y':
                drink = self.add_customisation_to_drink(drink)

        self.user.basket.items[drink_index] = drink


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: I think there's probably (?) enough code here to be on topic, but you would benefit from showing your other submodules - `user`, `display`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Strings

Given your current code, it doesn't make sense to have `Strings`. This kind of string centralization is typically seen if you're doing internationalization, but there's no evidence of that.

Among other problems, `Strings` isn't used whatsoever as a class - everything in it is static, so if you were to keep your centralised strings (which you shouldn't) the works could be turned into a module.

Detonate your `Strings` class and put the individual strings where they're used.

There's another code smell in that class - all of the `y/n` strings suggest that you should factor out a yes/no input method that prints that suffix, rather than baking it into each individual prompt. Also, `commands` should be generated from a command sequence, rather than hard-coded.

### Everything-on-construction

`Main()` does all of the work of `main_menu()` right in the constructor. That should be avoided; move the `main_menu()` call up to your entry point.

### Baked-in currency formatting

```
£{size.value.cost_multiplier * drink.cost}
```

should be replaced with a call to `locale.currency()`. Ensure that your locale is set correctly and the pound symbol will be added for you.